# connect() failed between selectionChanged and my pyQtSlot after updating from Qt4 to Qt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4, qwidget, qtreeview

I have recently been put onto a project which is using PyQt. It was using Qt4, but due to the pains of installing it on up-to-date systems, along with all other tools and packages, I decided to update everything to Python3, Qt5, etc..

In the old code,

```
self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed_event)
```

Was valid and worked.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot("QTreeView, QItemSelection, QItemSelection")
    def selection_changed_event(self, selected, deselected):
        """Event handler.
        Triggered by TreeView selection change.
        Get Title from selected/deselected items. Send SelectionEvent(title) to widgets to show/hide content as needed.
        :param selected: New selected item.
        :param deselected: Item that was selected.
        :return:
    """
```

Since updating to Qt5, it is now saying that the connect() has failed. Although I'm a noobie, my understanding is that I do indeed want to retrieve the view's `selectionModel` and then connect to its `selectionChanged` signal. So I should have the form of `self.ITEM.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.SLOT)`.
Within the slot, and it seems to fit the criteria, I should have the `QModelIndex` that tells what's selected during the event and the `QModelIndex` that tells what's deselected during the event.

So the only other notable change I've made to this is in the switch from QTGui to QtWidget. This was done due to a shift in QtGui and QtWidget from Qt4 to Qt5.

Old:

```
class QMenuTreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    selectionChangeEvent = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None, log=None):
        QtGui.QTreeView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        ...
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed_event)
```

New:

```
class QMenuTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    selectionChangeEvent = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None, log=None):
        QtWidgets.QTreeView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        ...             
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_changed_event)
```

Is there any other change between Qt4 and QT5 that I'm not understanding, and would be causing this?
It seems I cannot use QtGui as the reference to QTreeView is no longer valid, plus, it's listed in their docs as QtWidgets now. Is there anything else I need to convert, or is this connect() issue related to some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

That `pyqtSlot` syntax seems just wrong (even for PyQt4): the signature should *not* include the class of the view, since it's not part of the signal.
The reason for which it worked on PyQt4 is that in that version the slot decorator syntax and type checking was less strict than it's with PyQt5.

Consider that, in normal conditions, there should be no need for slot decorators (especially for "common" widgets and when not dealing with threads), so I'd start by removing the decorator at once, at least by commenting it.

Then, if that specific requirement is actually needed, the syntax should be:

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QItemSelection, QtCore.QItemSelection)
    def selection_changed_event(self, selected, deselected):
        # ...
```

Note that there are no quotes, they are only required for very specific situations in which PyQt doesn't provide the types and the slot requires them anyway (for instance, QStringList). Also, concatenation of arguments should *not* be within the same string.

This is correctly called and prints the two selections (note that:

```
    @pyqtSlot('QItemSelection', 'QItemSelection'):
    def test(self, selected, deselected):
        print(selected, deselected)
```

This raises an exception, as the slot only recognizes the first type, but the function expects two:

```
    @pyqtSlot('QItemSelection, QItemSelection')
    def test(self, selected, deselected):
        print(selected, deselected)
```

Finally, this works, but only the first argument is given:

```
    @pyqtSlot('QItemSelection, QItemSelection')
    def test(self, *args):
        print(args)
```

Comment: Interesting. Commenting that out seems to have cleared that error. I figured it was kept that way to help with some sort of C++ stuff that may get used. There are also some weird things done since they have custom versions of some QT Classes. Thank you!

Comment: @CNK13 using pyqtSlot is not a problem per se, and, as said, there are situations in which it is required, while normally using them or not doesn't really change that matter. The point is that that syntax was wrong in the first place, making their usage completely pointless. And subclassing Qt classes is not a problem at all, it's pretty normal for both Qt and PyQt. Anyway, remember that if an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray tickmark on its left.

Comment: My guess is that they tried to account for the 'self' type, hence the "QTreeView, QItemSelection, QItemSelection" I don't quite understand the original thought of having them all in one string... Separating them and removing the 'self' type seems to act as expected.